# Java Swing Drawing Rectangles

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to visualize values in an Integer Array.
They are supposed to be like a bar graph, but just the bars no axis etc
Im using Java Swing for the GUI.
This is supposed to draw just one rectangle for now, but no matter how high I increase the height in `g.fillRect(0,0,width,height)` it is drawn as a square.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel
{
...

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.fillRect(0,0,10,100);
}

public void draw()
{
    JFrame myframe = new JFrame("FrameTest");
    myframe.setSize(new Dimension (groesse,groesse));
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();
    mypanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    mypanel.setSize(new Dimension(256,256));

    mypanel.add(new MyClass(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    myframe.add(mypanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    myframe.setVisible(true);
}
```

I would love to post a picture of the output but SO doesn't want me to...

Comment: `I would love to post a picture of the output but SO doesn't want me to...` - post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) every time you ask a  question that demonstrates the problem. Then we can copy/compile/execute the code to see the problem if we wish.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BorderLayout` not `FlowLayout`. Don't add two components in the same `BorderLayout` area. Put your `MyClass` instance in `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Also override the `getPreferredSize` method of `MyClass` to an appropriate value (the size of your drawing area), and forget `setSize`; use `pack` to pack your frame before making it visible.

And finally, don't override `paint` when using swing but `paintComponent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, if i wanted to put the rectangle in the lower left corner, BorderLayout.South would not do anything. Is there a way to set the 0,0 point somewhere else instead of the left upper corner ?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a way by playing around with the x Koordinates and the height. Thanks !

Comment: Yes you can modify the coordinates system by setting an appropriate `AffineTransform` to the `Graphics2D`.

Answer (score 2):

```
mypanel.setSize(new Dimension(256,256));
```

Don't use setSize().

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of your class and don't forget to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)`. You would also override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the Dimension of your custom painting.

Now your component will have a preferred size and the layout manager can do its job.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for more information and working examples.

```
mypanel.add(new MyClass(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default. Specifying a BorderLayout constraint does nothing. You don't even need this panel, so get rid of it and just add the rectangle panel to the frame.